# Align Line number to Code snippet Vite React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, code-snippets, line-numbers

I'm new in Vite react js also with tailwind and its hard to deal with css to design my web app. In these problem, I'm trying to create a code snippet with a line number but it's hard to align these two
Here is my code

```
export const Democode = () => {
  const codeSnippet = `let name = prompt("What's your name?");
console.log("Hello, " + name + "!Welcome to our website.");`;

  return (
    <div className=" bg-slate-100 rounded-lg p-10">
      <pre className="col-span-2" style={{ position: "relative" }}>
        <div
          style={{
            fontSize: "20px",
            position: "absolute",
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            width: "1em",
            textAlign: "left",
            userSelect: "none",
            pointerEvents: "none",
            color: "rgba(0,0,0,.5)",
            paddingRight: "0.5em",
            paddingTop: "0.6em",
            paddingLeft: "2em",
          }}
        >
          {codeSnippet.split("\n").map((_, i) => (
            <span
              key={i}
              style={{ display: "block", counterIncrement: "line-number" }}
            >
              {i + 1}
            </span>
          ))}
        </div>
        <code
          style={{ fontSize: "20px", paddingLeft: "4em", textAlign: "left" }}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: Prism.highlight(
              codeSnippet,
              Prism.languages.javascript,
              "javascript"
            ),
          }}
        />
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O4sx.png)

To learn and fix my problem

Comment: There is a [React Prism renderer](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/prism-react-renderer) available. Maybe that can help?